# iPhone Saving Images to Documents Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am retrieving an image from the user's photo library, and saving that image in the documents directory.  I am currently naming the picture based on what the user enters in a text field.  This works, but the text field is not really a good name for the picture.  I would like to use some sort of unique identifier for naming the pictures.

Any ideas or suggestions?  I just do not want to have conflicts when a large amount of photos are saved by the user.

Comment: What about a timestamp + increment?

Comment: Does the title actually matter (eg will the user ever directly use/see the file)? If not, just use a UUID. Otherwise see my answer below for one idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use UUIDs. Here is an example:

```
// return a new autoreleased UUID string
- (NSString *)generateUuidString
{
  // create a new UUID which you own
  CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

  // create a new CFStringRef (toll-free bridged to NSString)
  // that you own
  NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuid);

  // transfer ownership of the string
  // to the autorelease pool
  [uuidString autorelease];

  // release the UUID
  CFRelease(uuid);

  return uuidString;
}
```

Or an ARC version:

```
// Create universally unique identifier (object)
CFUUIDRef uuidObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

// Get the string representation of CFUUID object.
NSString *uuidStr = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidObject);
CFRelease(uuidObject);
```

Even easier iOS6+ solution:

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

More info here:  http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/09/creating-guid-or-uuid-in-objective-c.html and here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday I had to solve the same exact problem with a few variations: Save the image in the temp directory because the picture was going to be uploaded to Dropbox.

What I did was to get the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch to rename the image.

Here is the whole method. You will need to modify it to suit your needs, but you should get the essentials to solve your problem out of it:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imageToUpload = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSDate *dateForPictureName = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [dateForPictureName timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSMutableString *fileName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeInterval];
    NSRange thePeriod = [fileName rangeOfString:@"."]; //Epoch returns with a period for some reason.
    [fileName deleteCharactersInRange:thePeriod];
    [fileName appendString:@".jpeg"];
    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 1.0)];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    [[self restClient] uploadFile:fileName toPath:currentPath withParentRev:nil fromPath:filePath];

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is that what the user enters has some meaning that you want to attach to the photo, then just increment a number on the end of the title until you find one that works

eg

> PicnicDay.jpg
>
> PicnicDay 1.jpg
>
> PicnicDay 2.jpg

Comment: the problem with this method, is that I will have to keep a count around so I know which number I currently at

Comment: @Vikings: No, you shouldn't do that (because you don't fully control the documents area anyways). You would just try each one and check if it already exists. If not, use that number.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think i'm going with the timestamp or UUID though